# storing and echoing session data in different pages

Tags: php, html, css, session, echo

i am coding a type of donation system for my Minecraft server and so i understand that i need a session to temporarily store the data the donator submitted in the form to echo it later.
so lets say the donator's username is Mister_Fix and the rank he wants to purcahse is Builder, the processor script gives him the right link, to pay for his rank, but then to prevent scam what i want to do is check his IP, (im not going to get into that here) and what he submitted in the form, that way ill be sure that it was him the submitted the form and ill be able to give him his rank.
so i need to store what he submitted in a session, but when i put a

```
session_start();
```

tag in my script, then try to echo $_SESSION['username']; on a different page it comes up blank, any solution to that?

Comment: I wouldn't use ip i would generate a transaction id and assign it to him throughout the transaction using it to cross reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_start();` Needs to be on all pages (in the very beginning) when you're calling the session info

Comment: i just added it to all pages, still nothing

Comment: Are you declaring a value for `$_SESSION['username']` as Moeed pointed out?

Comment: No, if i would it would be the same for everyone, but the form is a multi selection one

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare some value to `$_SESSION['username'];` and i think you are missing that.

For e.g:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user_name'] ;
```

If not,then keep `session_start();` in all pages to initialize the session otherwise it will be blank

Answer (score 0):

When you get your `$_POST` data in your script assign your `$_POST` data to a `$_SESSION` variable like so

```
 $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Then start your session...

```
session_start();
```

Then to clear your `$_SESSION` variables, do `session_destroy();`.